# DatabaseLockTimeout in sqlpackage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dma

I try to deploy my db project. Sometimes all goes good, but in some cases I have this exception: Lock request time out period exceeded.
I go to sql server profiler and find this:
[sql server profiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb0bf.png)

DacFx sets database lock timeout and I want to increase it. I have found this article on blogs.msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-configurationsettings, but on my machine I dont have Data Migration Assistant and folder `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Data Migration Assistant\` when should be `dma.exe.config` with following content:

```
<advisorGroup>

<advisorSettings>

<dacFx  commandTimeout="60" databaseLockTimeout="5000" maxDataReaderDegreeOfParallelism="8"/>

</advisorSettings>

</advisorGroup>
```

Can someone help me set database lock timeout to `20000`?

Comment: Have you downloaded DMA? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Comment: No, I dont have this utill. I only have installed SSDT and SQL Server (Developer)

Comment: Are you using SQLPackage.exe? If so, I believe that has the option to set timeout based on a parameter passed in.